# How to get finer control over sequence attributes in python C API?

Tags: python, python-c-api

I am trying to add a new class/type to python via C/C++. This particular class has a vector like attribute called `x`, it is a list but it is made only from **positive doubles**. I used the [`tp_getset`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getset) to have finer control over setting `x` when defined like:

`>>> obj.x=[1.0,2.5,3.5]`

I have total control over the setting of the attribute, and it works as expected and I can prevent user from doing:

```
>>> obj.x=[1.0,2.5,-4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "input.py", line 21, in <module>
   obj.x=[1.0,2.5,-4]
ValueError: 'x[2]' should be greater than or equal to 0.
```

or

```
>>> obj.x=[1.0,2.5,'str']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "input.py", line 21, in <module>
   obj.x=[1.0,2.5,'str'];
TypeError: fialure to deduce C++ type <double*>
```

and throw an exception. However, when `tp_getset.get` is defined which returns a list object of doubles, I do not have any control over the user doing the following:

```
>>> obj.x=[1.0,2.5,3.5]
>>> obj.x[2]=-3.6
```

I know that as a last resort I can just generate a list object with only one reference every time `tp_getset.get` and do not keep a reference inside the class so that `obj.x[2]` basically a temporary and nothing will happen

```
>>>obj.x=[1.0,2.5,3.5]
>>>obj.x[2]='str'
>>>print obj.x
[1.0,2.5,3.5]
```

My question is there a way to have this specific kind of control over sequence attributes of a class? for example.

```
>>> obj.x=[1.0,2.5,4]
>>> obj.x[2]=-3
File "input.py", line 21, in <module>
   obj.x[2]=-3
ValueError: 'x[2]' should be greater than or equal to 0.
```

EDIT: I just added more details for clarification

Comment: "I have total control ..." "... is there a way to have this specific kind of control ..." I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: sorry copy paste mistake I just fixed the end of the question

Comment: There is no language "C/C++". Only the to **distinct languages C and C++.   Don't spam tags, remove the tag for the unrelated language. And see [ask] and provide a [mcve].